# Why isn't variable 'k' incrementing? (C)

Tags: c

I want 'k' to increment to show the following pattern:-
A
BB
CCC
DDDD
but its showing
A
AA
AAA
AAAA instead. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{int k,i,n,j;
    printf("\nenter the size of pattern ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
    {k=65;
        for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
        {printf(" %c",k);
        if(i==j)
          printf("\n");
        }
     ++k;
    }
return 0;
}
```

And here is a [picture of pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFqkn.png) for reference.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You increment `k` in the outer loop. Try doing it in the inner loop.

Comment: Note: You should not use "magic" numbers. If you mean an `A`, use `'A'` instead of `65`

Comment: Aside it is idiomatic to loop like this `for(i=0; i<n; ++i)` instead of like this `for(i=1; i<=n; ++i)`. Then you'll be in the right habit when you use the loop variable to index arrays.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just starting out, I would advise you to use proper indentation in your code, it will make it easier to spot errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k, i, n, j;
    printf("\nenter the size of pattern ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        k = 65; // <---
        for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            printf(" %c", k);
            if (i == j)
                printf("\n");
        }
        ++k; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With each row, `k` will remain initialized to the same value, you should initialize it outside your loop.

Comment: sorry for improper indentation, but I want a different pattern like:- A than in next line BB than CCC than DDDD than EEEEE.

Comment: @GautamBisht Then you're initializing `k` to A's ASCII value each time you iterate on a new row.  Initialize `k` outside of your loop, and to avoid confusion, please edit your question and clarify what output did you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to move your `k` incrementor inside the nested `for` loop. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{int k,i,n,j;
    printf("\nenter the size of pattern ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
    {k=65;
        for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
        {printf(" %c",k);
        if(i==j)
          printf("\n");
          ++k;
        }
     
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I want a different pattern like:- A than in next line BB than CCC than DDDD than EEEEE.

Answer (score 0):

k , should have been placed inside the inner for loop .

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int k, i, n, j;
  printf("\nenter the size of pattern ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
  {
    k = 65;
      for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
      {
        printf(" %c", k);
        if (i == j)
          printf("\n");
        ++k;
      }
  }
return 0;
}
```